# Word Wrapping, Hyphenation, Text Justification

Tags: formatting

I'd like to use Mathematica to write up homework assignments and project reports. The problem is, the way I have it set up, it does not behave like a traditional word processor, and I don't know how to adjust settings so that it does. For example, when I write text in a text cell, words get chopped off when moving to a new line. Further more when I go to print these results, sometimes the words get hyphenated sometimes they don't. I've tried adjusting settings in the options inspector, under hyphenation options, and text justification, I've also tried different options for word wrapping. What I want to achieve is for the words to wrap properly, like they do in every other standard word processor, for example the way they do in this paragraph right here.

Comment: I do periodically try to use Mathematica for such tasks, but in the end I always go back to LaTeX.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. I cut and pasted the entire text of your post into a text cell in a notebook and it wrapped correctly, nothing was "chopped off". Can you try that? What do you observe?

Comment: To be clear, I have also never seen any words getting chopped off. I do see weird hyphenation from time to time. The question is not very well worded: it's vague and there is no clearly described answerable problem. If you see specific issues, please do provide precise instructions on how to reproduce them.

Comment: Like I said in my post in chops off the text. Its not chopping off the text on your system because yours is functioning properly. Mine is not. I don't know what setting got adjusted in the options inspector to cause this behavior I've described. The implied question here is, how do you return the settings back to where Mathematica word wraps properly? I thought that was clear. It's got to be something to do with the word wrapping, hyphenation, or text justification settings in the options inspector.

Comment: Okay I found the problem, LineBreakWithin was set to False. I changed it back to Automatic and now words are wrapping properly!

Comment: Are you exporting the notebook to PDF?